# How to prove the optimality of greedy algorithm in a change problem with binary coin values?

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, algorithms, computer-science

Consider the change making problem, the input to this problem is an integer L. The output should be the minimum cardinality collection of coins required to make L cents of change (that is, you want to use as few coins as possible). In Binaryland, the coins are worth $1$,$2$,$2^2$,$2^3$,...,$2^{1000}$ cents. Assume that you have an unlimited number of coins of each type. Prove or disprove that the greedy algorithm (that takes as many coins of the highest value as possible) solves the change problem in Binaryland.

I'm new to proofs and couldn't get far enough with induction or contradiction, so I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: My advice is to start by thinking about the problem rather than running down a checklist of proof techniques.  Why do you think the greedy algorithm is optimal?  Once you can articulate that, I doubt you'll have trouble with the proof.

Comment: I actually don't know how to reason through this either.

Comment: When will you use more than one of the same coin?

Answer (score 1):

For a proof with contradiction, you could use the following: Assume that you do not use a coin that has the highest possible value. Then, you will have to take a combination of coins that sums up to that amount exactly (this is the case since you use $1,2,2^2,..$) and the fact that you use more than one coin to get to the exact same amount concludes the proof since this contradicts the fact that you have a solution with a few coins as possible.

Hope this helps!